# DB2 query - select previous adjacent month until not exist?

Tags: sql, db2

This's example data.

```
 KEY |  MONTH   | NAME
  -------------------
  13 | 201311  |  A
  24 | 201310  |  B
  77 | 201309  |  C
  19 | 201307  |  D
  15 | 201304  |  E
```

I want to select previous adjacent month until not exits.

I expect results likes this.

```
 KEY |  MONTH   | NAME
  -------------------
  13 | 201311  |  A
  24 | 201310  |  B
  77 | 201309  |  C
```

Assume current MONTH is 201312.

Answer (score 0):

For the data that you have, you could do:

```
select t.m_key, t.name
from (select t.*,
             m_key + row_number() over (order by m_key) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
where grp = (select max(m_key) + 1 from table t);
```

I say "for the data that you have" because it is unclear what happens when you pass a year boundary.  Handling that case is a bit more complicated because you have to consider two keys adjacent when they don't differ by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. It will also handle years breaks `(..,201212,201301,...)`. In this query `(M_KEY/100)*12+MOD(M_KEY,100)` expression converts YEAR+MONTH format to MONTHS .

```
SELECT * FROM T
   WHERE M_KEY BETWEEN 
       (SELECT MAX(M_KEY) 
         FROM T as T1 
        WHERE M_KEY <= 201312
              AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T 
                              WHERE 
                              (M_KEY/100)*12+MOD(M_KEY,100) + 1 
                               = (T1.M_KEY /100)*12+MOD(T1.M_KEY,100)
                             ) 
       )
       AND 201312
```